# SQL Select everything after character

Tags: sql, sql-server-2016

I'd like to select everything AFTER  a certain character (-) that is placed on the most right side.

Eg.

```
abcd-efgh-XXXX
```

And I'd like to select the `XXXX` part

Thanks!

Comment: before what? What do You mean from the right?

Comment: before everything from the right? as in the last X chars? (where x is a static number). or everything from the last - on?  need some more examples, or a better description of what exactly you are looking for .

Comment: if length of `XXXX` this part is same for all then you can use right(column name,4)

Comment: Sorry, I've edited the question. Everything up to the first -, starting from the right.

Comment: Do You mean AFTER the MOST right certain character?

Answer (score 92, accepted):

You can use:

```
select right(col, charindex('-', reverse(col)) - 1)
```

Comment: Thank you for just answering the question, and not questioning or querying the intentions of the question asker.

Comment: add the following constraint. where charindex('-', col) > 0

Answer (score 5):

```
DECLARE @x varchar(100)
SET @x = 'abcd-efgh-XXXX'
SELECT RIGHT(@x, CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@x)) - 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

[Using string split available from SQLServer 2016](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/library/mt684588.aspx)

```
;with cte
as
(
 select 
*,row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rownum
 from string_split('abcd-efgh-XXXX','-')
)
select top 1 * from cte 
order by rownum desc
```

Comment: This was a good concept.  I'm on SQL 2014, so I don't have string_Split available, but I do have a user defined split function, that did the trick.  Thanks for the nudge in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

@thegameiswar had a clever solution, since I needed the results from a comma delimited list.  I don't have SQL 2016, so I made it work with a user defined split function.

```
;with cte
as
(
 select 
 *,row_number() over (order by (select null)) as rownum
 from database..[fn_SplitDelimitedList](@CommaDelimitedList,',')
)
select * from cte 
order by rownum desc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select substr('Prueba,Prueba2',instr('Prueba,Prueba2',',') + 1) from dual
```

Comment: `instr` is not known in my sql server.

Comment: Pretty sure that answer was for Oracle (based on the from dual)

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server Management Studio v15.0.18206.0 (18.4):

`RIGHT([col], CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE([col]), -1))`

Comment: Hey meraxes! Welcome to stack overflow.

You might want enclose your sql query in a code block.

Answer (score 0):

This is how to do the opposite of this question. i.e everything **before** the certain character that's placed on the right most side.  If anyone found this question looking for the opposite like I did...

```
DECLARE @x varchar(100)
SET @x = 'abcd-efgh-XXXX'
SELECT LEFT(@x,LEN(@x) - CHARINDEX('-', REVERSE(@x)))
```

Then you would get `abcd-efgh`

Answer (score -1):

Worked for me in the case you are using postgres:

```
SELECT RIGHT(col, POSITION('-' IN REVERSE(col))-1)
```

Swap out `POSITION` for `CHARINDEX`

Comment: I think OP mentioned sql server.