# Return all words starting with a character in a column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2014

I have a VARCHAR column with data like this:

```
abc = :abc and this = :that
```

I need a query to find all of the special "words" that start with a colon in this column of data. I don't really need any other data (IDs or otherwise) and duplicates would be OK. I can remove duplicates in Excel later if need be. So if this was the only row, I'd like something like this as the output:

```
SpecialWords
:abc
:that
```

I'm thinking it'll require a CHARINDEX or something like that. But since there could be more than one special word in the column, I can't just find the first : and strip out the rest.

Any help is greatly appreciated! Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to split this value based on spaces  and return only fields that starts with a colon `:`, i provided 2 solutions to achieve this based on the result type you need (Table or Single Value)

## Table-Valued Function

You can create a TV function to split this column into a table:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[GETVALUES] 
    (   
    @DelimitedString    varchar(8000)
    )
RETURNS @tblArray TABLE
    (
    ElementID   int IDENTITY(1,1),  -- Array index
    Element     varchar(1000)               -- Array element contents
    )
AS
BEGIN

    -- Local Variable Declarations
    -- ---------------------------
    DECLARE @Index      smallint,
                    @Start      smallint,
                    @DelSize    smallint

    SET @DelSize = 1

    -- Loop through source string and add elements to destination table array
    -- ----------------------------------------------------------------------
    WHILE LEN(@DelimitedString) > 0
    BEGIN

        SET @Index = CHARINDEX(' ', @DelimitedString)

        IF @Index = 0
            BEGIN

            IF ((LTRIM(RTRIM(@DelimitedString))) LIKE ':%')
                INSERT INTO
                    @tblArray 
                    (Element)
                VALUES
                    (LTRIM(RTRIM(@DelimitedString)))

                BREAK
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN

             IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1)))) LIKE ':%'
                INSERT INTO
                    @tblArray 
                    (Element)
                VALUES
                    (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1))))

                SET @Start = @Index + @DelSize
                SET @DelimitedString = SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, @Start , LEN(@DelimitedString) - @Start + 1)

            END
    END

    RETURN
END
```

And you can use it like the following:

```
DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(100)
SELECT @SQLStr = 'abc = :abc and this = :that and xyz = :asd'

SELECT
    *
FROM
 dbo.GETVALUES(@SQLStr)
```

*Result:*

[image]

## Scalar-Valued Function

If you need to return a value (not table) so you can use this function which will return on all values separated by *(line feed + carridge return `CHAR(13) + CHAR(10)`)*

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetValues2
(
    @DelimitedString    varchar(8000)
)
RETURNS varchar(8000)
AS
BEGIN

       DECLARE @Index      smallint,
                    @Start      smallint,
                    @DelSize    smallint,
                    @Result varchar(8000)

    SET @DelSize = 1
    SET @Result = ''

    WHILE LEN(@DelimitedString) > 0
    BEGIN

        SET @Index = CHARINDEX(' ', @DelimitedString)

        IF @Index = 0
            BEGIN

            if (LTRIM(RTRIM(@DelimitedString))) LIKE ':%'
           SET @Result = @Result + char(13) + char(10) +  (LTRIM(RTRIM(@DelimitedString)))

                BREAK
            END
        ELSE
            BEGIN

             IF (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1)))) LIKE ':%'

                    SET @Result = @Result + char(13) + char(10) + (LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, 1,@Index - 1))))

                SET @Start = @Index + @DelSize
                SET @DelimitedString = SUBSTRING(@DelimitedString, @Start , LEN(@DelimitedString) - @Start + 1)

            END
    END


    return @Result
END
GO
```

you can use it as the following

```
DECLARE @SQLStr varchar(100)
SELECT @SQLStr = 'abc = :abc and this = :that and xyz = :asd'

SELECT dbo.GetValues2(@SQLStr)
```

*Result*

[image]

in the table result line feed are not visible, just copy the data to an editor and it will appears as shown in the image

**References**

- [Splitting the string in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21428612/splitting-the-string-in-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

One way is to write a specialized SPLIT function.   I would suggest getting a TSQL Split function off the internet and see if you can adapt the code to your needs.

Working from scratch, you could write a function that loops over the column value using CHARINDEX until it doesn't find any more `:` characters.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a  `charindex`?

[rextester](http://rextester.com/XWGMF92873) sample:

```
create table mytable (testcolumn varchar(20))
insert into mytable values ('this = :that'),('yes'), (':no'), ('abc = :abc')


select right(testcolumn, charindex(':', reverse(testcolumn)) - 1) from mytable
where testcolumn like '%:%'
```

**reference**:

[SQL Select everything after character](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38973852/sql-select-everything-after-character)

**Update**

Addressing Sami's:

Didn't see that two words could be in one colon, how about this?

```
select replace(substring(testcolumn, charindex(':', testcolumn), len(testcolumn)), ':', '')
```

**Update again**

I see, the actual statement is `this = :that and that = :this`

Comment: What about `this = :that :lose`?

Comment: I tried running yours on rextester, but if you feed it "this = :that and that = :this" it fails because there are 2 things with : in them in the same column

Answer (score 0):

If performance is important then you want to use an inline table valued function to split the string and extract what you need. You could use [delimitedSplit8K](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/72993/) or [delimitedSplit8K_lead](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/SQL+Server+2012/106903/) for this.

```
declare @string varchar(8000) = 'abc = :abc and this = :that';

select item 
from dbo.DelimitedSplit8K(@string, ' ')
where item like ':%';
```

**returns:**

```
item
------
:abc
:that
```

And for even better performance than what I posted above you could use [ngrams8k](http://www.sqlservercentral.com/articles/Tally+Table/142316/) like so:

```
declare @string varchar(8000) = 'abc = :abc and this = :that';

select position, item = 
  substring(@string, position,
    isnull(nullif(charindex(' ',@string,position+1),0),8000)-position)
from dbo.ngrams8k(@string, 1)
where token = ':';
```

This even gives you the location of the item you are searching for:

```
position   item
---------- -------
7          :abc
23         :that
```

Answer (score 0):

I would use a recursive CTE. https://learnsql.com/blog/recursive-cte-sql-server/

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS #allwords;
CREATE TABLE #allwords (id INT, S VARCHAR(MAX));

INSERT INTO #allwords (id, S)
VALUES
(1, 'abc = :abc and this = :that'),
(2, 'abc = :abc'),
(3, 'abc = :abc this = :that other = :other another = :another');

WITH recursivecte
AS (SELECT id,
           S,
           SUBSTRING(   S,                        --Original String
                        CHARINDEX(':', S, 0) + 1, -- First separator
                        ABS(CHARINDEX(   ' ', -- Abs for missing space
                                         S,
                                         CHARINDEX(':', S, 0)
                                     ) - CHARINDEX(':', S, 0)
                           )
                    ) AS Token,
           SUBSTRING(S, CHARINDEX(':', S, 0) + 1, LEN(S)) AS TokenRemoved
    FROM #allwords a
    WHERE CHARINDEX(':', S, 0) > 0
    UNION ALL
    SELECT id,
           S,
           SUBSTRING(
                    TokenRemoved,
                    CHARINDEX(':', TokenRemoved, 0) + 1,
                    ABS(CHARINDEX(' ', TokenRemoved, CHARINDEX(':', TokenRemoved, 0)) - CHARINDEX(':', TokenRemoved, 0))
                    ),
           SUBSTRING(TokenRemoved, CHARINDEX(':', TokenRemoved, 0) + 1, LEN(TokenRemoved)) AS TokenRemoved
    FROM recursivecte R
    WHERE CHARINDEX(':', TokenRemoved, 0) > 0)
SELECT id, S, Token FROM recursivecte ORDER BY id, LEN(recursivecte.TokenRemoved) DESC;
```

| id | S | Token |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | abc `=` :abc and this `=` :that | abc |
| 1 | abc `=` :abc and this `=` :that | that |
| 2 | abc `=` :abc | abc |
| 3 | abc `=` :abc this `=` :that other `=` :other another `=` :another | abc |
| 3 | abc `=` :abc this `=` :that other `=` :other another `=` :another | that |
| 3 | abc `=` :abc this `=` :that other `=` :other another `=` :another | other |
| 3 | abc `=` :abc this `=` :that other `=` :other another `=` :another | another |